# Derivative with respect to two variables

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

We fix $d \in \mathbb{N}^*$ and let us define a $C^1$ mapping $f:(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{d}\times \mathbb{R}^{d}\mapsto f(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Now we define the mapping $g: (a,b)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^d\mapsto f(x,ax+b)$

I want to calculate the derivative of $g$ w.r.t $(a,b)$ i.e $\nabla_{(a,b)}f(x,ax+b)$.

This is what I ve found :
$$\nabla_{(a,b)}f(x,ax+b) = \nabla_y f(x,ax+b).x +\nabla_y f(x,ax+b),$$
since $\partial_a (ax+b)= x$ and $\partial_b(ax+b)=1$.

Comment: I get the same result. Since you're sometimes putting $y$ in as the second input of $f$ and sometimes not, it might be safer to write $\nabla_2f$ instead of $\nabla_yf$ (meaning the partial gradient with respect to the second input vector, which is consistent; instead of with respect to the input called $y$, which is inconsistent). But otherwise I can find no flaw.

Comment: @TobyBartels I agree with your suggestion of the notation, but I think it should not be the sum of the two, maybe the vector representation $(\nabla_2 f(x,ax+b).x   \,\, \nabla_2 f(x,ax+b))$. Also I think It might be a dimension problem

Comment: Ah, you are right, it's not the sum!  This is a problem with checking; since I expect the correct answer, I see the correct answer even if what you wrote is a little different.  They should be side-by-side matrix components as you write them in your comment.

Comment: Regarding the dimension, $\nabla_2f$ is a $d$-by-$d$ matrix, which becomes a $d$-by-$1$ matrix when you multiply by the $d$-dimensional vector $x$ (which we can also think of as a $d$-by-$1$ matrix).  Stick this $\nabla_2f.x$ next to $\nabla_2f$, and you get a $d$-by-$(1+d)$ matrix, which is what we should have, since $g\colon \mathbb R^{1+d}\to\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: @TobyBartels I agree, the dimensions are correct, so does the result.